# Unable to get the states when rendering the dynamic inputs/select

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm trying to create a form where extra details can be added on button click
When I'm trying to enter the value in the first input box, it just gets copied to the second input box and further on I'm not able to change its value too(This keeps on happening with all the input boxes you dynamically add)
On submitting these value I get an alert(which is fine, I was trying to fetch the state) but the main concern is the value of 2 inputs shouldn't be the same.

What I feel is I'm messing up the **value={}** of the  **tag**

Can someone help me here, please?

https://codesandbox.io/s/array-form-11-q0pyr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: sandbox isn't working

Comment: You didn't imported `react-dom`,
add import ` ReactDOM from 'react-dom' `
that`s one error. Still looking for the others.

Comment: add `import  ReactDOM from 'react-dom'` to your import and I believe you're missing a closing curly brace for your AddInvoice class.. this should fix the codesandbox

Comment: You don't have an event handler on save button.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/array-form-11-luk2f

Comment: Got it to render. Definitely some issues though. Can you be more clear with what you are trying to oaccomplish?

Comment: Thank you for joining the community. Please explain your problem here instead of posting a link, so its easier to help you.

Comment: @TimWilson I have updated the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow steps to remove bugs

1- import----> `import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';`

2- add------->} (closing curly brace) at the end

3- add------->`react-router-dom` in dependencies

and about saving data or updating state

```
handleAddRow = () => {
    const item = {
        name: "",
        mobile: "",
        btn: ""
    };
    console.log(item)
    // this.setState({
    //     rows: [...this.state.rows, item]
    // });
};
```

if you don't want to add another fields without updating/saving data 
then first save and then on successful response add your fields/component.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import `ReactDOM` from react-dom, thats the first issue.

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

The second issue you didn't add `react-router-dom` as Dependency.
You can`t use route without that.

```
npm install react-router-dom
```

You also didn`t close the class parenthesis as @Aasim afridi said.

Look at the fixed link  @Tim Wilson gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Saurabh,

i fixed your issue first you did not close class paranthesis and then you have not imported react dom in your class. So now it's fixed.